# What Goes on in Photosystems at the Molecular/Atomic Level?

Tags: biochemistry, photosynthesis

In light-harvesting complexes, how is the energy of a photon transferred from one pigment molecule to another? And in reaction-center complexes, how does the primary electron acceptor capture an electron from the chlorophyll *a*? It’d be best if any of you could explain this to me in terms of what’s happening at the molecular or atomic level, say with electrons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The energy transfer is achieved by a process called "resonance energy transfer". It needs the positioning of the donor and the acceptor in very close proximity to each other - the light harvesting complexes are optimized for this. This allows the collection of small amounts of light energy and still enables photosynthesis. The figure shows how this works schematically:

[image]

The figure is from this [webpage](http://employees.csbsju.edu/hjakubowski/classes/ch331/oxphos/olphotsynthesis.html), which gives a good introduction.